# Reading a few rows from Bigquery as a side input, getting None

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am having trouble with side inputs, specifically BQ, for dataflow pipelines, even after going on coursera and looking at the samples.

Right now, I have a pipeline that reads files in a gcs bucket, gets their filenames, and then transforms the file and writes a given number of rows to bigquery. I am trying to figure out how to map the filename to a specific "key" from bq.

```
result = [m.metadata_list for m in gcs.match(['gs://{}/countries*'.format(BUCKET)])]
result = reduce(add, result)
#create each input PCollection name
variables = ['p{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(result))]
```

Based on the result, I build a tuple of all the filenames (filename1, filename2…) create a query dynamically that is: 
`Bqquery = "SELECT FILENAME, FILE_ID from 'project:dataset.table' where FILENAME IN (filename tuple)"` I thought I would do this as it will be approximately 20 files at once so it would make sense to get the data from bq once instead of having to get the file_id inside the for loop.

So I did

```
Bqcollection = p | 'Get File_Id' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=bqquery))
But the result I get is none 


for i in range(len(result)):
    current_file = result[i].path
    #query inside for loop 
    #bqquery= "SELECT FILE_ID" from 'project:dataset.table' where FILENAME = '{0}'".format(current_file)
   # file_id = p | 'GetFile_id_{0}'.format(i) >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=bqquery))
    globals()[variables[i]] = p | read_labels[i] >> ReadFromText(result[i].path) | add_filename_labels[i] >> beam.ParDo(AddFilenamesFn(), current_file)
```

I also tried doing the query inside of the for loop to just get one filename at a time (see the commented out code) but that didn't work either. Ultimately what I want to do is change `beam.Pardo(AddFilenamesFn(), current_file)` to `beam.Pardo(AddFileNamesFn(), file_id)` so instead of adding the actual filename I'm adding the fileid

[note the label mentions in the code (i.e. read_labels[i]) are just labels for dataflow]

I assume i'm missing something pretty basic about pcollections, but not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest solution, taking into account the code in the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404579/dataflow-apache-beam-how-to-access-current-filename-when-passing-in-pattern) would be to run the queries inside the `AddFilenamesFn` ParDo within the for loop. Keep in mind that `beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=bqquery))` is used to read rows as source and not in an intermediate step. So, in the case I propose, you can use the Python Client Library directly (`google-cloud-bigquery>0.27.0`):

```py
class AddFilenamesFn(beam.DoFn):
    """ParDo to output a dict with file id (retrieved from BigQuery) and row"""
    def process(self, element, file_path):
        from google.cloud import bigquery

        client = bigquery.Client()
        file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]

        query_job = client.query("""
            SELECT FILE_ID
            FROM test.file_mapping
            WHERE FILENAME = '{0}'
            LIMIT 1""".format(file_name))

        results = query_job.result()

        for row in results:
          file_id = row.FILE_ID

        yield {'filename':file_id, 'row':element}
```

This would be the most straight-forward solution to implement but it might arise an issue. Instead of running all ~20 possible queries at the start of the pipeline we are running a query for each line/record. For example, if we have 3,000 elements in a single file the same query will be launched 3,000 times. However, each different query should be actually run only once and subsequent query "repeats" will hit the [cache](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#disabling_retrieval_of_cached_results). Also note that cached queries do not contribute towards the interactive query [limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs).

I used the same files of my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459687/6121516):

```sh
$ gsutil cat gs://$BUCKET/countries1.csv
id,country
1,sweden
2,spain

gsutil cat gs://$BUCKET/countries2.csv
id,country
3,italy
4,france
```

and added a new table:

```sh
bq mk test.file_mapping FILENAME:STRING,FILE_ID:STRING
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'INSERT INTO test.file_mapping (FILENAME, FILE_ID) values ("countries1.csv", "COUNTRIES ONE"), ("countries2.csv", "COUNTRIES TWO")'
```

[image]

and the output is:

```sh
INFO:root:{'filename': u'COUNTRIES ONE', 'row': u'id,country'}
INFO:root:{'filename': u'COUNTRIES ONE', 'row': u'1,sweden'}
INFO:root:{'filename': u'COUNTRIES ONE', 'row': u'2,spain'}
INFO:root:{'filename': u'COUNTRIES TWO', 'row': u'id,country'}
INFO:root:{'filename': u'COUNTRIES TWO', 'row': u'3,italy'}
INFO:root:{'filename': u'COUNTRIES TWO', 'row': u'4,france'}
```

Another solution would be to load all the table and materialize it as a side input (depending on size this can be problematic of course) with `beam.io.BigQuerySource()` or, as you say, break it down into N queries and save each one into a different side input. Then you could select the appropriate one for each record and pass it as an additional input to `AddFilenamesFn`. It would be interesting to try to write that one, too.

Full code for my first proposed solution:

```py
import argparse, logging
from operator import add

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io.filesystem import FileMetadata
from apache_beam.io.filesystem import FileSystem
from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsfilesystem import GCSFileSystem

class GCSFileReader:
  """Helper class to read gcs files"""
  def __init__(self, gcs):
      self.gcs = gcs

class AddFilenamesFn(beam.DoFn):
    """ParDo to output a dict with file id (retrieved from BigQuery) and row"""
    def process(self, element, file_path):
        from google.cloud import bigquery

        client = bigquery.Client()

        file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]

        query_job = client.query("""
            SELECT FILE_ID
            FROM test.file_mapping
            WHERE FILENAME = '{0}'
            LIMIT 1""".format(file_name))

        results = query_job.result()

        for row in results:
          file_id = row.FILE_ID

        yield {'filename':file_id, 'row':element}

# just logging output to visualize results
def write_res(element):
  logging.info(element)
  return element

def run(argv=None):
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

  p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
  gcs = GCSFileSystem(PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
  gcs_reader = GCSFileReader(gcs)

  # in my case I am looking for files that start with 'countries'
  BUCKET='BUCKET_NAME'
  result = [m.metadata_list for m in gcs.match(['gs://{}/countries*'.format(BUCKET)])]
  result = reduce(add, result)

  # create each input PCollection name and unique step labels
  variables = ['p{}'.format(i) for i in range(len(result))]
  read_labels = ['Read file {}'.format(i) for i in range(len(result))]
  add_filename_labels = ['Add filename {}'.format(i) for i in range(len(result))]

  # load each input file into a separate PCollection and add filename to each row
  for i in range(len(result)):
    globals()[variables[i]] = p | read_labels[i] >> ReadFromText(result[i].path) | add_filename_labels[i] >> beam.ParDo(AddFilenamesFn(), result[i].path)

  # flatten all PCollections into a single one
  merged = [globals()[variables[i]] for i in range(len(result))] | 'Flatten PCollections' >> beam.Flatten() | 'Write results' >> beam.Map(write_res)

  p.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```