# How to get all file metadata from PCollection<string> in beam

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have a flattened PCollection that contains paths of files

```
PCollection<String> "/this/is/a/123/*.csv , /this/is/a/124/*.csv"
```

```
flattenPCollection = pcs.apply(Flatten.<String>pCollections());
```

I want to read each file and get the file name and process

```
        flattenPCollection
                .apply("Read CSV files", FileIO.matchAll())
                .apply("Read matching files",FileIO.readMatches())
                .apply("Process each file", ParDo.of(new DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, String>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void process(@Element FileIO.ReadableFile file) {
                        // We shloud be able to file and its metadata.
                        logger.info("File Metadata resourceId is {} ", file.getMetadata().resourceId());
                      // here we read each line and process
                    }

                }));
```

The following error is occurring

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No files matched spec: bob,22,new york
```

it seems like the pipeline is reading the first lines of the csv file and looking for that string in the filesystem.

What is causing this to happen?

I want to get each file as FileIO.ReadableFile

I am sure its something very simple that I am missing. Any help is appreciated

UPDATE

If you have a PCollection of paths and files you have manually loop over each one and add a ParDo

```
        for(String path : pathList) {
            pipeline.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(path))
                    .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                    .apply(
                            ParDo.of(
                                    new DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, String>() {
                                        @ProcessElement
                                        public void process(@Element FileIO.ReadableFile file) throws IOException {
                                            logger.info("Metadata - " + file.getMetadata());
                                            logger.info("File Contents - " + file.readFullyAsUTF8String());
                                            logger.info("File Metadata resourceId is " + file.getMetadata().resourceId());
                                        }
                                    }));
        }
```

Thanks to @bigbounty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404579/dataflow-apache-beam-how-to-access-current-filename-when-passing-in-pattern

Answer (score -1):

```
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
pipeline.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern("/Users/bigbounty/Documents/beam/files/*.txt"))
                .apply(FileIO.readMatches())
                .apply(
                        ParDo.of(
                                new DoFn<FileIO.ReadableFile, String>() {
                                    @ProcessElement
                                    public void process(@Element FileIO.ReadableFile file) throws IOException {
                                        LOG.info("Metadata - " + file.getMetadata());
                                        LOG.info("File Contents - " + file.readFullyAsUTF8String());
                                        LOG.info("File Metadata resourceId is " + file.getMetadata().resourceId());
                                    }
                                }));
PipelineResult pipelineResult = pipeline.run();
pipelineResult.waitUntilFinish();
```

Output:

```
Metadata - Metadata{resourceId=/Users/bigbounty/Document/beam/files/3.txt, sizeBytes=7, isReadSeekEfficient=true, lastModifiedMillis=0}
Metadata - Metadata{resourceId=/Users/bigbounty/Document/beam/files/1.txt, sizeBytes=7, isReadSeekEfficient=true, lastModifiedMillis=0}
Metadata - Metadata{resourceId=/Users/bigbounty/Document/beam/files/2.txt, sizeBytes=7, isReadSeekEfficient=true, lastModifiedMillis=0}
File Contents - hello-1
File Metadata resourceId is /Users/bigbounty/Document/beam/files/1.txt
File Contents - hello-2
File Metadata resourceId is /Users/bigbounty/Document/beam/files/2.txt
File Contents - hello-3
File Metadata resourceId is /Users/bigbounty/Document/beam/files/3.txt
```