# Add file name and timestamp into each record in BigQuery using Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a few .txt files with data in JSON to be loaded to google BigQuery table. Along with the columns in the text files I will need to insert filename and current timestamp for each rows. It is in GCP Dataflow with Python 3.7

I accessed the Filemetadata containing the filepath  and size using GCSFileSystem.match and metadata_list.

I believe I need to get the pipeline code to run in a loop, pass the filepath to ReadFromText, and call a FileNameReadFunction ParDo.

```
   (p
        | "read from file" >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
        | "parse" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
        | "Add FileName" >>  beam.ParDo(AddFilenamesFn(), GCSFilePath)
        | "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(known_args.output,          
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
     )
```

I followed the steps in [Dataflow/apache beam - how to access current filename when passing in pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404579/dataflow-apache-beam-how-to-access-current-filename-when-passing-in-pattern) but I can't make it quite work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using apache_beam.io.fileio's Match transforms?

Answer (score 1):

You can use textio.ReadFromTextWithFilename instead of ReadFromText.  That will produce a PCollection of (filename,line) tuples.

To include the file and timestamp in your output json record, you could change your "parse" line to

```
| "parse" >> beam.map(lambda (file, line): {
    **json.loads(line),
    "filename": file,
    "timestamp": datetime.now()})
```

Comment: while it gets file name , throws error in the Json parsing step.       
        | "read from file" >> ReadFromTextWithFilename(known_args.input)
        | "parse" >> beam.Map(json.loads)
as it excepts a string to parse, with file name it will be a tuple.

Also I need to add Current TimeStamp to each row and later an audit file with all files processed. That is why I thought of looping through all files.

Comment: I've added some more detail to the answer

Comment: What could be wrong ,I get TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'line' [while running 'parse']
        | "read from file" >> ReadFromTextWithFilename(input_bucket)
        | "parse" >> beam.Map(lambda file, line: {"row": json.loads(line),"filename": file,"timestamp": datetime.datetime.now()})

Comment: thanks @danielm , lamba function doesn’t automatically unpack a tuple into two arguments in python. fixed the parse step by using  | "parse" >> beam.Map(lambda file: {"row": json.loads(file[1]),"filename": file[0]}) . so it appends the filename to the row.
Writing to BQ fails as the  output of the parse step is simialr to 
{'row': {'ClientID': '66.155' 'RuleID': 5073,  'Country': 'Italy'}, 'filename': 'gs://bucket-test/request.log'}, Any guidance on this?

Comment: What failure do you get? You might just need to delete your table first, since the output schema will be different now that your json structure is different

Comment: this is the error  message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.'
 reason: 'invalid'> [while running 'WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs']
"
Schema is good, I am successful in loading the file to same BQ without filename field (simply parse with jason.loads) . It looks like the output format isn't compatible.

Comment: I think you need to flatten the json, instead of having the nested "row" field.  Updated answer

Comment: no luck. instead of using lambda I called a custom function that appends filename to the dict and dump it as json like this        filecontents = json.loads(file[1])
        filecontents['filename'] = file[0]. With this the row format is clean but fails to load to BQ with same error. If I write the output to a file and then load the file to BQ then it succeeds. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there anything more in the error message? Dataflow is also doing the same thing of writing the output json to a file, then loading that file into BQ.

Comment: Fixed it, I had to do a json.loads before sending it to BQ. Thanks a lot.